# How to use fancybox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to use fancybox to popup a message if a certain button is clicked.
I want the fancybox message to only contain some text, 
and a 'close' button, i dont mind using the default button if there is one.

can someone give an example of how it should be written in the html page and the js page?

any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your button has an id of yourButton:

```
$("#yourButton").click(function () {
    var content = $("<div>Hello<br /><br /></div>");
    var button = $("<input type='button' value='Close Me!' />");
    content.append(button);

    $.fancybox({ content: content });
    $(button).click(function () { $.fancybox.close(); });
});
```

Comment: it works, but the window instantly refreshing and i cant view the message, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This should be able to help you:

http://fancybox.net/howto

Once you have required all the relevant files, to hook it up to all linka, use this:

```
$("a").fancybox();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the html is complicated enough you might prefer putting it in a hidden div as I've done below. This is a scaled down version of code I'm running on my site to do a fancybox dialog box. Works with FancyBox version 1.3.4 (I haven't upgrade to 2 yet). Personally, I like the default close button (circle X in top right corner) and even pressing Escape works, but I've added a custom close button to the popup. It includes javascript to close FancyBox.

```
<a id="mylink" href="#mypopup">link style button</a>
<div id="mybutton">button</div>

<div style="display:none">
<div id="mypopup">
<h1>My Title</h1>
<p>My Message</p>
<!--... other complex html can go here ...-->
<input type="button" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" value="Custom Close Button" />
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mylink').fancybox();
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'orig' : $(this),
        'href' : '#mypopup'
    })
});
</script>
```